# How to solve "extra data given to DerValue constructor"?

Tags: java, certificate

The following codes (*sun.security*) are written to add the *authority information access* to a certificate.

```
`ObjectIdentifier objectIdentifier15=new ObjectIdentifier("1.2.3");
byte[] byte15=new byte[]{1,2,5};
DerValue derValue15=new DerValue(byte15);
GeneralName generalName15=new GeneralName(derValue15);
AccessDescription accessDescription1=new AccessDescription(objectIdentifier15, generalName15);
ArrayList<AccessDescription> accessDescriptions=new ArrayList<AccessDescription>();
accessDescriptions.add(accessDescription1);
certificateExtensions.set(AuthorityInfoAccessExtension.NAME, new AuthorityInfoAccessExtension(accessDescriptions));`
```

But an IOException occurs:

```
`java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:384)
    at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:294)`
```

How to solve this problem?